# React Native: Flatlist not rendering

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

My React Native Flatlist is not rendering. It does not show any error nor does the app crash. It just shows an empty view. I made a dummy data on another file just for an example.

UpcomingEventScreen.js

```
 const UpcomingEventScreen = ({}) => {
        return (
            <GrayCustomView>
                <HeaderBar2/>
                <EventTitle>Upcoming Events</EventTitle>
                <FlatListContainer>
                   <EventListCell history={UpcommingEventData}/> 
                </FlatListContainer>
            </GrayCustomView>
        );
    }
```

EventList.js

```
export const EventListCell = (history) => {
    const renderItem = ({item}) => (
        <EventListContainer activeOpacity={0.8} onPress={undefined} >
            <EventListImage source={item.image} resizeMode="cover"/>
            <EventListTitleContainer>
                <EventListTitle>{item.title}</EventListTitle>
            </EventListTitleContainer>
            <EventListBottomContainer>
                <EventListLeftContainer>
                    <EventListVenue>{item.venue}</EventListVenue>
                    <EventListDate>{item.date}</EventListDate>
                </EventListLeftContainer>
                <EventListRightContainer>
                    <EventListFee>{item.price}</EventListFee>
                </EventListRightContainer>
            </EventListBottomContainer>
        </EventListContainer>
    )

    return (
        <FlatList 
            scrollEnabled={true}
            data={history}
            keyExtractor={item => item.id}
            renderItem={renderItem}
            showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
        />
    ); 
};
```

dummy.js

```
export const UpcommingEventData = [
    {
        id: 1,
        image: "https://d1csarkz8obe9u.cloudfront.net/posterpreviews/business-event-banner-design-template-392070a11089eb5fb736443db6abef83_screen.jpg?ts=1618400029",
        title: "Business Event",
        venue: "Online",
        date: "Sat 19 May 2022",
        price: 55.00,
    }
];
```

Comment: you can apply View as a parent element of flatlist then apply width and height over view check it is displaying or not, or you can apply contentContainerStyle on Flatlist as well

Answer (score 0):

In your **Flatlist** renderItem function, do a console log to make sure that the **Flatlist** is getting rendered.

`renderItem={renderItem}`

Now if it logs fine, then check the styles of **GrayCustomView** and **FlatListContainer** Do they have flex:1 on them or at least a height and width.

If this was not helpful then you need to share the code of these components as well.